# laravel recursive relationship with directed acyclic graph

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm, recursive-datastructures

i have table "task" and relationship many to many with itself

```
    public function depends_on() //parents
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DependentTask::class, 'task_id');
    }

    public function dependents() //kids
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DependentTask::class, 'dependent_id');
    }
```

the relationship may be like this

[image: the relationship may be like this]

i want to select the tasks  like this

first print  5 or 2

then  3 and 6

then  4 and 1

how can i do it by laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use recursive relations:

```
public function dependsOn()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Account', 'task_id','dependent_id');
}

public function dependents()
{
   return  $this->dependsOn()->with('dependents');

}
```

Then:

```
$dependents = Dependents::with('dependents')->first();

$dependents->dependents; 

$dependents->dependents->first()->dependents; // .. and so on
```

Comment: i want to get all tasks as a tree  According to the accreditation like this image 
[link(]https://www.coitok.com/image/original/1/directed-acyclic-graph-xjWMM.png)
i want to get task like 
F - E  - C   - D  B  - A  G